# If the columns of a Matriz are Lineal Dependet, Col(Matrix) = R3?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem solving this question, we have this matrix

$M=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -8 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 7\\ 
0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$

This is what I have, if we apply Gauss - Jordan, we have that this matrix have 2 pivot columns that it means we have Col(M) = Span {a1,a3} so we have dimension 2  si this is my question I don't know if we can say that is different to R3
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb R^3$ is $3$ dimensional.  The span of *two* vectors is at most $2$ dimensional.  In your case the rows give two linearly independent  vectors.  So the dimension of the column space is $2$.  Thus we can say that we don't have all of $\mathbb R^3$.  Note that I have employed a famous theorem that the dimension of the row space is equal to that of the column space.

In fact, all you need to know in order to know that the span is not all of $\mathbb R^3$ is that the three columns are a dependent set.  For instance, the second and third rows are multiples of each other.  (There was that theorem again.)

Comment: Thank you! very much this helps me a lot.